# Android : Description parts of my ListView's cells are not displayed

Tags: android, listview

I have the following XML code for my cells (search_cell.xml) :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

   <TextView android:id="@+id/libelle"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:textSize="16dp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/valeur"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:textSize="10dp"
             android:textStyle="normal"
             />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity xml file :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listRecherche"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" >
</ListView>
```

And in Java :

list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRecherche);

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("libelle", "Microsoft");
    map.put("valeur", "1975");
    listItem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("libelle", "Apple");
    map.put("valeur", "1976");
    listItem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("libelle", "Dell");
    map.put("valeur", "1984");
    listItem.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.recherche_cell,
            new String[] {"libelle", "valeur"}, new int[] {R.id.libelle, R.id.valeur});

    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

And here is what I get. Why can't I see the year fields ?

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: may be because you set the textview height as fill_parent , try using wrap_content .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this new search_cell.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

   <TextView android:id="@+id/libelle"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="16dp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/valeur"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="10dp"
             android:textStyle="normal"
             />

</LinearLayout>
```

you used fill_parent for the first textview height parameter. so this fills the entire parent. so, i changed the eight parameter to 'wrap_content'

Comment: if it helped you, mark it as an answer, so that it help others also

Comment: Don't worry I'll do it, just have to wait until I can.

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_height="fill_parent" Will occupy the whole height.Instead try android:layout_height="Wrap_content",It will take upto the content what you have.